# BASH indexed arrays in Cygwin

Tags: arrays, bash, cygwin

--As requested

**GNU Bash: version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)**

**Cygwin Version: 2.8.2 (i think, or whatever is the most current)**

**Windows Server 2012R2**

**EDIT** <sup>(*requested to update with an actual example that can be verified*)</sup>

```
testdir=$(mktemp -t -d testdir.XXXXXX)
cd "$testdir/" && touch file{1..99}
read -r -a ARRAY <<< $(ls -alh "$testdir" | grep -Eo "file[0-9]{2}") 
# grep above grep should ignore 0-9 (single digits)
```

In proper Linux shell: `echo "${ARRAY[@]}"` returns `file10 file11 file12 file13 file14 file15 ..... file99`

In a proper Linux shell: `echo "${ARRAY[5]}"` returns: `file15`

In Cygwin shell: `echo "${ARRAY[@]}"` returns `file10`

In Cygwin shell: `echo "${ARRAY[5]}"` returns nothing (as nothing indexed)

```
for i in "${!ARRAY[@]}"; do echo "Key: $i"; echo "Value: ${ARRAY[$i]}"; done
```

In a proper Linux Shell:

```
Key: 0
Value: file10
```

...

```
Key: 89
Value: file99
```

In Cygwin:

```
Key: 0
Value: file10
file11
file12
file13
file14
```

...etc.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW:**

I'm using Cygwin for the first time and I'm having a hard time understanding why my indexed array does populate properly:
This has worked fine in a proper Linux shell, which I've double checked to make sure i'm not losing my mind:
Which gets a long list of results, all properly indexed with unique keys ... whether wrong or right, this is how I learned to do it, and its always worked for me.

**When I do this *exact* same thing in Cygwin, I only get one result.**

If I do `declare -a ARRAY` and then `ARRAY=$(stuff to do, results populate the array)` I get many results, but all stored under a single key.

I feel I must be missing something basic, because I don't think it should be this hard.

Comment: `array=$(foo)` *always* stores content in only one key. Everywhere. That's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to include a proper [mcve]? That is to say, not just `$(stuff to do)`, but a concrete example; maybe `$(echo "one two three")`. The essential part is that you (1) test it to produce the exact same problem, and (2) specify the exact software versions, so we can install the same release of cygwin and its bash and reproduce.

Comment: Using bash 4.3.39(2)-release on CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW, `read -r -a array <<<"hello cruel world"; declare -p array` properly emits as output `declare -a array='([0]="hello" [1]="cruel" [2]="world")'`

Comment: BTW, the behavior of `read` depends on the current value of `IFS`. Do be sure you include it in the question if it's anything other than the default.

Comment: ...so, thank you for the updates. **However**, the updated code works perfectly for me, even in cygwin; the problem isn't reproducing.

Comment: Could you check that your `IFS` value is still at defaults? I'm wondering if something in your environment (`~/.bashrc` or similar) might be changing it. Can you still reproduce the bug if you `unset IFS` first?

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming that the code at hand is just an example, but just in case it isn't -- you [should never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The correct alternative in this use case would be a glob expression, such as `shopt -s nullglob; array=( "$tempdir"/file[0-9][0-9] ); array=( "${array[@]##*/}" )` (the second phase strips off the directory names, leaving only filenames).